# How to make a variable able to be set only once in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

I want to declare a variable, and assign it later, but I want the variable to be able to be assigned once.

The `readonly` keyword doesn't do this. The documentation says:

> assignment to the field can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

The `const` keyword also doesn't do this.
So how do I make a variable able to be set only once?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a nullable property, where the setter will only set a value if it's null

Comment: What do you mean by "able to be set only once"? What do you want to happen if someone *tries* to set it multiple times? A compile-time error? An exception? No-op? Without that information, it's impossible to answer. Also note that both answers so far are about *properties*, which aren't variables. Are you actually interested in properties?

Comment: If someone tries to set it multiple times, then it will not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a private nullable variable like this, in this way, `_myVar` just once gets value

```
   private bool? _myVar = null;
    public bool? MyVar
    {
        set { if (_myVar == null) _myVar = value; }
        get { return _myVar; }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

To do this, first you have to make a bool variable that tells you if the variable has been set:

```cs
bool isSet;
```

Then, we make the variable be true when the variable you want to be able to be set only once is set.

```cs
private int exampleVar
public int ExampleVar {
    get {
        return exampleVar; 
    }
    set {
        if(isSet) {
            exampleVar = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this returns null if this variable is accessed before it is set.
To fix it, replace everything inside get{} with:

```cs
if(isSet) {
    return exampleVar; 
}
return /* insert placeholder variable here */;
```

This also works if `exampleVar` and `ExampleVar` is another type of variable, such as `float`.

Comment: So you wrote the question, wrote an incorrect answer, then submitted them in short order? To what end?

Comment: Maybe his name NOT_A_ROBOT is a lie?

Comment: Property is not a variable... so not an answer. And even if question would be about property suggestion is incomplete and worse than existing answers. Please make sure to search for similar questions before asking and use proper names for things.

Comment: I am answering my own question, stackoverflow says they encourage it.